Laravel - Catching an already handled exception with Pest
I am using Laravel and Pest here.
I'm trying to assert that an Exception is thrown within a test.
my function is like
public static function stuff(): void
{
        DB::beginTransaction();

        try {
            [$width, $height, $type] = $this->getImageSize($path);

            $model->update([
                'width' => $width,
                'height' => $height,
                'type' => image_type_to_mime_type($type),
            ]);

            DB::commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::error($e->getMessage());
            DB::rollBack();
        }
}

the function that throws the error:
    private function getImageSize($path): ?array
    {
        if (! Storage::disk('images_admin')->exists($path)) {
            throw new Exception("Image not found: $path");
        }

        $file = Storage::disk('images_admin')->path($path);
        $data = getimagesize($file);

        return [
            $data[0],
            $data[1],
            $data[2],
        ];
    }

and the test :
it('should not fill width, height and type of image if path is not found', function () {
    $model = Image::factory()->create([
        'path' => 'images/image.jpg',
    ]);

    Log::spy();
    
    expect(SaveImageMetadata::run(fn () => $model, 'images/not-found.jpg'))->toThrow(Exception::class);
    //    SaveImageMetadata::run($model, 'images/not-found.jpg');

    Log::shouldHaveReceived('error')
    ->withArgs(function ($message) {
        return $message === "Image not found: images/not-found.jpg";
    })
    ->once();

    expect($model->width)->toBeNull();
    expect($model->height)->toBeNull();
    expect($model->type)->toBeNull();
})

The test result i get:
Exception "Exception" not thrown.

Is there a way to catch the error within my test even though it's already been catch ?
When i remove the try catch or when i re throw an Exception in the catch, it is working but I am not sure that's what

You can write a test for the getImageSize method and check if it throws an exception. Basically, you can divide your current test.

Mock Log facade and assert that log is writen.

you can like ->throws(Exception::class);, see the ref.
